Model binding of dictionaries as part of a form in Minimal API
If you take a look at this blog post:
https://libertus.dev/posts/apsnet-dictionary-model-binder/
I'm trying to achieve exactly the same, just with the minimal api.
In the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/apis?view=aspnetcore-8.0
It specifically says:

No built-in support for model binding (IModelBinderProvider,
IModelBinder). Support can be added with a custom binding shim.

So, basically the same thing as it is in the blog post, just without the
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new EnhancedDictionaryBinderProvider());
});

since we're working with the minimal api and not controllers.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Well, there is direct way of doing this and can be found in this article about model binding in Minimal APIs:
app.MapPost("/todos", async ([FromForm] string name,
    [FromForm] Visibility visibility, IFormFile? attachment, TodoDb db)

In your case, I would suggest extracting IFormFile to separate parameter, and put all the rest to the model, like below:
public class UploadRequest
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Model { get; set; }
}

and endpoint definition:
app.MapPost("/upload", ([FromForm] UploadRequest request, IFormFile file, CancellationToken token)

In Swagger, it looks like this:

